# Error sending email from VBScript

Tags: email, vbscript, email-attachments

When running the following script I get the errors -2147220975 and Transport code error: 0x80040217

```
on error resume next

Const schema   = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
Const cdoBasic = 1
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
Dim oMsg, oConf

Set oMsg      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
oMsg.From     = "tom.watt.vulpes@gmail.com"  
oMsg.To       = "tom.watt.vulpes@gmail.com"    
oMsg.Subject  = "Test from VBScript"
oMsg.TextBody = "If you can read this, the script worked!"
objMsg.AddAttachment "C:\BLA_BLA.txt"

Set oConf = oMsg.Configuration
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpserver")       = "smtp.gmail.com" 
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpserverport")   = 465              
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendusing")        = cdoSendUsingPort
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic         
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpusessl")       = True             
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendusername")     = "tom.watt.vulpes@gmail.com" 
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendpassword")     = "PASSWORD"      
oConf.Fields.Update()

oMsg.Send()


If Err Then
    resultMessage = "ERROR " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear()
Else
    resultMessage = "Message sent ok"
End If

Wscript.echo(resultMessage)
```

I've tried countless scripts from the internet but none of them seem to work. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks, Tom

EDIT: I am running Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transport code error: 0x80040217 can be a few different things depending on the situation. The links below should guide you in the right direction...

[Overflowing Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157087/getting-error-transport-error-code-was-0x80040217-while-sending-email-in-asp-net)

[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2bdde9e6-b57a-4b12-b476-7bcf1f8f66d5/reporting-services-using-smtp-email-get-transport-error-0x80040217?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Legendary, Cheers! Don't have enough reputation to upvote sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I have found that may help in relation to this was that the domain I was wanting to use this script for had a SPF record with a hard fail attached to it and so then only their specific email server would work with this which in my case was Office 365 but when testing I was using their ISP and attempting to relay unauthenticated through them.

So check SPF also, hope this helps.

Cozzie