# The transport error code was 0x80040217 - cannot send using asp.classic and CDO

Tags: email, vbscript, asp-classic, cdo.message

According to the many posts on the web, the error message

> The message could not be sent to the smtp server. The transport error code was 0x80040217. The server response was not available

Basically means [it doesn't authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157087/getting-error-transport-error-code-was-0x80040217-while-sending-email-in-asp-net) because of a faulty user name/password

The problem I have is I run the mail server. I push emails on my .net websites fine, this issue only exists when using CDO

The email, username and password are correct, it's stored in plain text in the .asp file

```
Set MyMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set MyConfig = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")

'MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "name@example.co.uk"
'MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "passwordIsHere"
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "127.0.0.1" 'also tried with localhost, the actual IP of server and mail.example.co.uk (which is set up correctly)
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587 ' also tried 25
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
MyConfig.Fields.Update
```

Any ideas why, on my W2012 server, I can run my asp.classic website, but cannot send the email?

The email account works fine when I send mail from MS outlook. The fault is only here, in the script.

Comment: It doesn't mean the username / password is wrong *(that is just a possible symptom)*. It means that the Mail Server did not send a response, which can be for a number of reasons. Things to check, username and password, account usage limits, account status *(is it blocked)* etc.

Comment: Well, the username is the same as the email address. The password for testing is only 4 digits long and very obvious so I'm convinced to typos.

Comment: Although you do realise that in that example the `sendusername` and `sendpassword` is commented out??

Comment: ... I hate everything

Comment: Please answer it! And I'll accept this stupid question will remain forever. It was the issue of the comments @Lankymart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a weird conversion in the comments

The issue is likely because *(with correct syntax highlighting)* the `sendusername` and `sendpassword` `CDO.Configuration` properties are commented out, so it is likely the mail server is failing to authenticate.

Just remove the comments and you should be good to go.

```
Set MyMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set MyConfig = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")

MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "name@example.co.uk"
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "passwordIsHere"
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "127.0.0.1" 'also tried with localhost, the actual IP of server and mail.example.co.uk (which is set up correctly)
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587 ' also tried 25
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
MyConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
MyConfig.Fields.Update
```

Comment: Yes, I was reading the code in notepad, via an RDP session with a screen resolution of 800 * 600. As such, the code was all over the place, I just missed this and had spent a long time on it. Thanks

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions That explains it.