# VB6 Sending Email using Gmail as a remote SMTP server

Tags: email, vb6, gmail, cdo.message

I have 2 applications that are written in VB6 each send email via CDO and GMAIL account. The applications worked perfectly for a couple of years. No changes to Code nor to the account from my side. But today when I tried to send an email I got an SMTP Error code 0x80040217. Then I tried the second application and I got the same error. I can remember that when I created the gmail account I had to enter the settings and select an option that I can't remember now. (Tried to look it in the account settings) but can't find it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Error Transport error code was 0x80040217 while Sending Email in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157087/getting-error-transport-error-code-was-0x80040217-while-sending-email-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

I found the missing setting that was changed (not by me) it is.
 Enable Less Secure Apps. - must be enabled other wise you can't send emails.